# Include JavaScript code into HTML. Not all working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to include my JavaScript code into my HTML code. I implemented the code all in one file and now I'm trying to split it into 3 files (.html, .css, .js). The thing is: if in put the JavaScript script into the .js file and the put a `<src>` into the HTML file, it won't work properly (but only partially). I have to do this with multiple files.
For example, how can I split this file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>GAME</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, gold, limegreen);
    }

    h1, h2, h3 {
      margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: green;
      font: bold 52px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902;
    }

    h1:hover {
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
      left: -3px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902, 4px 4px #fe4902, 5px 5px #fe4902, 6px 6px #fe4902;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #time {
      color: navy;
      font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #score {
      color: blue;
      font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h2 {
      color: orange;
      font: bold 34px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
      color: navy;
      font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .oggettoElements {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 32px;
    }

    .oggetto {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 64px;
      margin: 0px 8px;
      cursor: move;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }

    .oggetto:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .contenitore {
      height: 104px;
      width: 128px;
      margin: 16px auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 64px;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 3px dashed #111;
      transition: border-width 0.2s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.4s;
    }

    .flexcontainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .contenitore span {
      font-size: 20px;
      pointer-events: none; 
    }

    .contenitore.contenitore-hover {
      border-width: 5px;
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }

    .contenitore.dropped {
      border-style: solid;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .contenitore.dropped i {
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .oggetto.dragged {
      user-select: none;
      opacity: 0.1;
      cursor: default;
    }

    .oggetto.dragged:hover {
      opacity: 0.1;
    }

    .tabella {
      height: 70%;
      width: 20%;
      margin: 16px auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    body > section {
      display: table;
      align: center;
    }

    section.oggettoElements {
      display: table-row;
    }

    section.oggettoElements > div {
      display: table-cell;
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      visibility: hidden;
      text-align: center;
    }

    section.oggettoElements > div > div {
      display: flex;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100px;
      align-items: center;
    }

    div > span {
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center
    }

    #gioca {
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .tree {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      margin: 16px auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .flexalberi {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    #nuovaPartita {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div onClick="GoToMainMenu();"><h1>Trash CAN or trash CAN't?</h1></div>
<div id="gioca" onclick="timerApparizioni();">
  <h2><u>GIOCA</u>
    <h3>
</div>

<div><h3>Abbina il rifiuto al bidone giusto!</h3></div>

<div id="nuovaPartita" onClick="history.go(0);" style="visibility:hidden;"><h2>
  GIOCA ANCORA</h2></div>
<div id="score">Punteggio: 0</div>

<section class="flexalberi">
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita1"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita2"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita3"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
</section>

<section class="contenitore-elements flexcontainer">
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-1"
       style="color: #0000FF;"><span>Carta</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-2"
       style="color: #008000;"><span>Vetro</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-3"
       style="color: #FFD700;"><span>Plastica</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-4"
       style="color: #8B4513;"><span>Organico</span></div>
</section>

<section class="tabella">
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="fas fa-prescription-bottle oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-32">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-bone oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-42">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-flask oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-22">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-box-open oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-12">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-11">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-21">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-31">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-41">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-hourglass oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-23">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-drumstick-bite oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-43">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="far fa-map oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-13">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-utensils oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-33">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-file oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-14">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fas fa-cookie-bite oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-44">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-shopping-bag oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-34">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-vial oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-24">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>


<script>
  const delay = 3000;

  function timerApparizioni () {
    timerOggetti = setInterval(apparizioneOggetto, delay);
  }

  let tuttiVisibili = false;

  function apparizioneOggetto (eve) {
    let oggettoScelto, colonna, riga;
    tuttiVisibili = !(
      Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="c-"]'))
        .some((pe_grid) => { return pe_grid.style.visibility !== 'visible'; })
    );
    if (tuttiVisibili) {
      document.getElementById('gioca').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      do {
        colonna = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        riga = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        oggettoScelto = document.querySelector(`#c-${colonna}${riga}`);  // In alternativa: document.getElementById(`c-${colonna}${riga}`)
      } while (oggettoScelto.style.visibility === 'visible');
      oggettoScelto.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

  function GoToMainMenu () {
    location.href = 'mainMenu.html';
  }

  const oggettoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.oggetto');
  const contenitoreElements = document.querySelectorAll('.contenitore');

  var vite = 3;
  var score = 0;
  const divScore = document.getElementById('score');
 
  oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  });

  contenitoreElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    ogg.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver); 
    ogg.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    ogg.addEventListener('drop', drop); 
  });

  function dragStart (event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
  }

  function dragEnter (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.target.classList.add('contenitore-hover');
    }
  }

  function dragOver (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  function dragLeave (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.target.classList.remove('contenitore-hover');
    }
  }

  var counterRightDropped = 0;

  function drop (event) {

    event.target.classList.remove('contenitore-hover');
    const idAccettabileContenitore = event.target.getAttribute('idAccettabile');  
    const idOggetto = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');  
    const sottostringaID = idOggetto.substr(0, 3); 

    const vita1 = document.getElementById('vita1');
    const vita2 = document.getElementById('vita2');
    const vita3 = document.getElementById('vita3');

    const giocabutton = document.getElementById('gioca');
    const nuovaPart = document.getElementById('nuovaPartita');

    if (sottostringaID === idAccettabileContenitore) {
      const oggettoGiusto = document.getElementById(idOggetto);
      oggettoGiusto.classList.add('dragged');
      oggettoGiusto.setAttribute('draggable', 'false');
      score++;
      counterRightDropped++;
      divScore.innerText = 'Punteggio: ' + score;
    } else {

      if (vita1.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        vita1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else if (vita3.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        vita3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }

      score = score - 2;
      divScore.innerText = 'Punteggio: ' + score;
      vite = vite - 1;

      if (vite == 0) {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        setTimeout(function () {
          alert('GAME OVER! \nVite-Alberelli esauriti! \nPunteggio finale: ' + score);
        }, 20);
        clearInterval(timerOggetti);

        nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }

    if (counterRightDropped === 16) {
      giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
        ogg.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-check-circle oggetto');
      });
      setTimeout(function () {
        alert('HAI VINTO! \nPunteggio finale: ' + score);
      }, 50);
      clearInterval(timerOggetti);

      nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried by putting all the script part into a .js file named JSTEST.js and then inserting this into the HTMLfile:

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSTEST.js"></script>
```

The thing is, it won't work anymore. It does only some things, partially.

So now I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>GAME</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSTEST.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JSTEST.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div onClick="GoToMainMenu();"><h1>Trash CAN or trash CAN't?</h1></div>
<div id="gioca" onclick="timerApparizioni();">
  <h2><u>GIOCA</u>
    <h3>
</div>

<div><h3>Abbina il rifiuto al bidone giusto!</h3></div>

<div id="nuovaPartita" onClick="history.go(0);" style="visibility:hidden;"><h2>
  GIOCA ANCORA</h2></div>
<div id="score">Punteggio: 0</div>

<section class="flexalberi">
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita1"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita2"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita3"
     style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
</section>

<section class="contenitore-elements flexcontainer">
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-1"
       style="color: #0000FF;"><span>Carta</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-2"
       style="color: #008000;"><span>Vetro</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-3"
       style="color: #FFD700;"><span>Plastica</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-4"
       style="color: #8B4513;"><span>Organico</span></div>
</section>

<section class="tabella">
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="fas fa-prescription-bottle oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-32">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-bone oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-42">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-flask oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-22">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-box-open oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-12">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-11">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-21">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-31">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-41">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-hourglass oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-23">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-drumstick-bite oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-43">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="far fa-map oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-13">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-utensils oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-33">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-file oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-14">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fas fa-cookie-bite oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-44">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-shopping-bag oggetto" draggable="true"
         style="color: #000000;" id="c-34">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-vial oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;"
         id="c-24">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>

</body>
</html>
}
```

and

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  const delay = 3000;

  function timerApparizioni () {
    timerOggetti = setInterval(apparizioneOggetto, delay);
  }

  let tuttiVisibili = false;

  function apparizioneOggetto (eve) {
    let oggettoScelto, colonna, riga;
    tuttiVisibili = !(
      Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="c-"]'))
        .some((pe_grid) => { return pe_grid.style.visibility !== 'visible'; })
    );
    if (tuttiVisibili) {
      document.getElementById('gioca').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      do {
        colonna = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        riga = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        oggettoScelto = document.querySelector(`#c-${colonna}${riga}`);  // In alternativa: document.getElementById(`c-${colonna}${riga}`)
      } while (oggettoScelto.style.visibility === 'visible');
      oggettoScelto.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

  function GoToMainMenu () {
    location.href = 'mainMenu.html';
  }

  const oggettoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.oggetto');
  const contenitoreElements = document.querySelectorAll('.contenitore');

  var vite = 3;
  var score = 0;
  const divScore = document.getElementById('score');

  oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  });

  contenitoreElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter); 
    ogg.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver); 
    ogg.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave); 
    ogg.addEventListener('drop', drop); 
  });

  function dragStart (event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
  }

  function dragEnter (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.target.classList.add('contenitore-hover');
    }
  }

  function dragOver (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  function dragLeave (event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('dropped')) {
      event.target.classList.remove('contenitore-hover');
    }
  }

  var counterRightDropped = 0;

  function drop (event) {

    event.target.classList.remove('contenitore-hover');
    const idAccettabileContenitore = event.target.getAttribute('idAccettabile'); 
    const idOggetto = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    const sottostringaID = idOggetto.substr(0, 3); 

    const vita1 = document.getElementById('vita1');
    const vita2 = document.getElementById('vita2');
    const vita3 = document.getElementById('vita3');

    const giocabutton = document.getElementById('gioca');
    const nuovaPart = document.getElementById('nuovaPartita');

    if (sottostringaID === idAccettabileContenitore) {
      const oggettoGiusto = document.getElementById(idOggetto);
      oggettoGiusto.classList.add('dragged');
      oggettoGiusto.setAttribute('draggable', 'false');
      score++;
      counterRightDropped++;
      divScore.innerText = 'Punteggio: ' + score;
    } else {

      if (vita1.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        vita1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else if (vita3.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        vita3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }

      score = score - 2;
      divScore.innerText = 'Punteggio: ' + score;
      vite = vite - 1;

      if (vite == 0) {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        setTimeout(function () {
          alert('GAME OVER! \nVite-Alberelli esauriti! \nPunteggio finale: ' + score);
        }, 20);
        clearInterval(timerOggetti);

        nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }

    if (counterRightDropped === 16) {
      giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
        ogg.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-check-circle oggetto');
      });
      setTimeout(function () {
        alert('HAI VINTO! \nPunteggio finale: ' + score);
      }, 50);
      clearInterval(timerOggetti);

      nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps. If you have any advice also about the code, please write them ;)

Comment: Why have TWO jQuery? Just have `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Actually why have jquery at all. You do no seem to use it anywhere

Comment: A friend advised me that... I'll try by removing it

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a single [mcve] and explain what the issues are

Comment: Also you cannot have script tags inside an external JS file

Comment: I tried by removing it, but nothing changed. It still displays error

Comment: I dont' see where you are waiting on the dom to finish loading. You should put your script reference at the bottom of the file, and you also make sure that the document is ready. If you're using jquery, there is a document ready function that you can use.

Comment: Ok, so I removed jquery and the script tags inside the .js file. Now I'm trying with @JayJordan's advice. btw, where can I find an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: This is the error I find by splitting:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
giocoTEST.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: timerApparizioni is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (giocoTEST.html:19)

Also, drag and drop stop working

Comment: What is expected result / behavior when this is working properly?

Comment: Posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the game needs full screen to see the trash

See the different panes. The css pane can go in a css file and the JS pane content can go into your external JS file. No need for jQuery here at all

The link tag and the external JS script goes into the head and so does the link to your external CSS file

I do not understand what "runme" does, it seems not important

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("gioca").addEventListener("click", timerApparizioni);
  if (document.getElementById("runme")) {
    document.getElementById("runme").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let SIZE = 4;
      let r = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1;
      let c = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1;
      document.querySelector("section.oggettoElements:nth-of-type(" + r + ") i:nth-child(" + c + ")").style.color = "#FF0000";
    })
  }
})
```

```js
const delay = 3000;

// Funzione per iniziare a giocare: quando l'utente preme "gioca" iniziano ad apparire gli oggetti e si avvia un timer
function timerApparizioni() {
  timerOggetti = setInterval(apparizioneOggetto, delay);
}

let tuttiVisibili = false;

// Funzione per prendere un oggetto a caso della tabella e renderlo visibile
function apparizioneOggetto(eve) {
  let oggettoScelto, colonna, riga;
  tuttiVisibili = !(
    Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="c-"]'))
    .some((pe_grid) => {
      return pe_grid.style.visibility !== 'visible';
    })
  );
  if (tuttiVisibili) {
    document.getElementById('gioca').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    do {
      colonna = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
      riga = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
      oggettoScelto = document.querySelector(`#c-${colonna}${riga}`); // In alternativa: document.getElementById(`c-${colonna}${riga}`)
    } while (oggettoScelto.style.visibility === 'visible');
    oggettoScelto.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("gioca").addEventListener("click", timerApparizioni);
  if (document.getElementById("runme")) {
    document.getElementById("runme").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let SIZE = 4;
      let r = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1;
      let c = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1;
      document.querySelector("section.oggettoElements:nth-of-type(" + r + ") i:nth-child(" + c + ")").style.color = "#FF0000";
    })
  }
})


// funzione per andare alla pagina "menu principale"
function GoToMainMenu() {
  location.href = "mainMenu.html";
}


// PARTE INIZIALIZZAZIONE gioco

// seleziono per classe oggetti e contenitori
const oggettoElements = document.querySelectorAll(".oggetto");
const contenitoreElements = document.querySelectorAll(".contenitore");

// punteggio e vite
var vite = 3;
var score = 0;
const divScore = document.getElementById("score");


// PARTE DEI LISTENERS per il gioco

// Aggiungo un listener ad ogni oggetto per "ascoltare" quando inizia il drag 
oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
  ogg.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
});

// Aggiungo più listener ad ogni elemento per "ascoltare" cosa succede tra l'inizio del drag e la sua fine (drop)
contenitoreElements.forEach(ogg => {
  ogg.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto è posizionato sopra ad un contenitore
  ogg.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto è rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore
  ogg.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto va via da un contenitore
  ogg.addEventListener("drop", drop); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto viene rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore
});


// PARTE DEGLI EVENTI DRAG AND DROP per il gioco

// Evento "inizio a prendere un oggetto"
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}

// Se un oggetto viene posizioneto sopra al contenitore, viene aggiunto "contenitore-over" alla classe del contenitore
// Determina l'effetto visivo dell'ingrandirsi di un contenitore quando un oggetto viene trascinato sopra
function dragEnter(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
    event.target.classList.add("contenitore-hover");
  }
}

// "Lascia il comando all'itente": evita la gestione di default e impedisce che venga droppato in automatico
function dragOver(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* developer.mozilla.org
    Il metodo preventDefault() dell'interfaccia Event dice all'user agent che se l'evento non viene esplicitamente gestito, 
    la sua azione predefinita non dovrebbe essere presa come normalmente. L'evento continua a propagarsi come al solito, 
    a meno che uno dei suoi listener di eventi non chiami stopPropagation() o stopImmediatePropagation(), uno dei due 
    interrompa la propagazione contemporaneamente. */
  }
}

/* Se un oggetto viene posizionato sopra ad un contenitore, esso viene ingrandito dalla funzione dragEnter.
Se poi il giocatore "cambia idea", e trascina lontano dal contenitore il suo oggetto, esso deve tornare della misura iniziale
Rimuovo "contenitore-over" dalla classe del contenitore */
function dragLeave(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
    event.target.classList.remove("contenitore-hover");
  }
}


var counterRightDropped = 0;

/* gestione del rilascio/drop: Se l'oggetto viene rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore:
- il contenitore ritorna della misura iniziale di default (come in dragLeave, viene rimosso "contenitore-over" dalla classe)
- viene fatto un confronto tra l'id parziale dell'oggetto e l'id accettabile dal contenitore.
- Se l'abbinamento è giusto (ossia confronto = true), viene aggiunto "dragged" alla classe dell'oggetto, facendo in modo che non sia più disponibile 
  (effetto visivo css) ne' prendibile (draggable=false)
- Viene incrementato o decrementato il contatore del punteggio a seconda dell'esisto del confronto */
function drop(event) {

  event.target.classList.remove("contenitore-hover");
  const idAccettabileContenitore = event.target.getAttribute("idAccettabile"); // Prendo l'id che il contenitore accetta
  const idOggetto = event.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // Con dragStart ho settato l'attributo text a "event.target.id". Qui lo riprendo (ex: "11")
  const sottostringaID = idOggetto.substr(0, 3); // Sottostringa dell'id dell'oggetto (ex. da "13" a "1")

  const vita1 = document.getElementById("vita1");
  const vita2 = document.getElementById("vita2");
  const vita3 = document.getElementById("vita3");

  const giocabutton = document.getElementById('gioca');
  const nuovaPart = document.getElementById("nuovaPartita");

  if (sottostringaID === idAccettabileContenitore) {
    const oggettoGiusto = document.getElementById(idOggetto);
    oggettoGiusto.classList.add("dragged");
    oggettoGiusto.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
    score++;
    counterRightDropped++;
    divScore.innerText = "Punteggio: " + score;
  } else {

    if (vita1.style.visibility === "visible") {
      vita1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (vita3.style.visibility === "visible") {
      vita3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
      vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    score = score - 2;
    divScore.innerText = "Punteggio: " + score;
    vite = vite - 1;

    if (vite == 0) {
      vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';

      giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("GAME OVER! \nVite-Alberelli esauriti! \nPunteggio finale: " + score);
      }, 20)
      clearInterval(timerOggetti);

      nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

  if (counterRightDropped === 16) {
    giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
      ogg.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-check-circle oggetto");
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("HAI VINTO! \nPunteggio finale: " + score);
    }, 50)
    clearInterval(timerOggetti);

    nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, gold, limegreen);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font: bold 52px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902;
}

h1:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902, 4px 4px #fe4902, 5px 5px #fe4902, 6px 6px #fe4902;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#time {
  color: navy;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#score {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: orange;
  font: bold 34px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: navy;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

.oggettoElements {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 32px;
}

.oggetto {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  cursor: move;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.oggetto:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.contenitore {
  height: 104px;
  width: 128px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px dashed #111;
  transition: border-width 0.2s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.4s;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contenitore span {
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* The element is never the target of pointer events */
}

.contenitore.contenitore-hover {
  border-width: 5px;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.contenitore.dropped {
  border-style: solid;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenitore.dropped i {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.oggetto.dragged {
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: default;
}

.oggetto.dragged:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.tabella {
  height: 70%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body>section {
  display: table;
  align: center;
}

section.oggettoElements {
  display: table-row;
}

section.oggettoElements>div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

section.oggettoElements>div>div {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

div>span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center
}

#gioca {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

.tree {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexalberi {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nuovaPartita {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css">
<div onClick="GoToMainMenu();">
  <h1>Trash CAN or trash CAN't?</h1>
</div>
<div id="gioca">
  <h2><u>GIOCA</u>
    <h2>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Abbina il rifiuto al bidone giusto!</h3>
</div>


<div id="nuovaPartita" onClick="history.go(0);" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <h2>GIOCA ANCORA</h2>
</div>
<div id="score">Punteggio: 0</div>

<!-- section contenente le vite-alberelli -->
<section class="flexalberi">
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita1" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita2" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita3" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
</section>

<!-- section contenente i contenitori (fissi) in cui andranno trascinati gli oggetti -->
<section class="contenitore-elements flexcontainer">
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-1" style="color: #0000FF;"><span>Carta</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-2" style="color: #008000;"><span>Vetro</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-3" style="color: #FFD700;"><span>Plastica</span></div>
  <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-4" style="color: #8B4513;"><span>Organico</span></div>
</section>

<!-- Tabella contenente gli oggetti che appariranno sullo schermo durante la partita -->
<section class="tabella">
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="fas fa-prescription-bottle oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-32">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-bone oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-42">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-flask oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-22">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-box-open oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-12">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-11">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-21">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-31">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-41">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-hourglass oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-23">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-drumstick-bite oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-43">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="far fa-map oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-13">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-utensils oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-33">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="oggettoElements">
    <div class="far fa-file oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-14">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fas fa-cookie-bite oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-44">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-shopping-bag oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-34">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fas fa-vial oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-24">
      <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I agree with you. The problem seems to be in the part of code that you wrote above. The game is "slow". by clicking "GIOCA" (play), it should start a timer and make objects appear in the lower half of the window. I posted the whole code because when I use it as a unique file it works, but splitting it generates the error you wrote or gives problems not enabling the drag and drop part

Comment: @hellomynameisA So the code I posted above actually works if I enlarge the screen enough to see the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, with errors, with the following changes.

```js
$(function() {
  const delay = 3000;

  // Funzione per iniziare a giocare: quando l'utente preme "gioca" iniziano ad apparire gli oggetti e si avvia un timer
  function timerApparizioni() {
    timerOggetti = setInterval(apparizioneOggetto, delay);
  }

  let tuttiVisibili = false;

  // Funzione per prendere un oggetto a caso della tabella e renderlo visibile
  function apparizioneOggetto(eve) {
    let oggettoScelto, colonna, riga;
    tuttiVisibili = !(
      Array
      .from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="c-"]'))
      .some((pe_grid) => {
        return pe_grid.style.visibility !== 'visible';
      })
    );
    if (tuttiVisibili) {
      document.getElementById('gioca').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      do {
        colonna = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        riga = 1 + Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        oggettoScelto = document.querySelector(`#c-${colonna}${riga}`); // In alternativa: document.getElementById(`c-${colonna}${riga}`)
      } while (oggettoScelto.style.visibility === 'visible');
      oggettoScelto.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }


  // funzione per andare alla pagina "menu principale"
  function GoToMainMenu() {
    location.href = "mainMenu.html";
  }


  // PARTE INIZIALIZZAZIONE gioco

  // seleziono per classe oggetti e contenitori
  const oggettoElements = document.querySelectorAll(".oggetto");
  const contenitoreElements = document.querySelectorAll(".contenitore");

  // punteggio e vite
  var vite = 3;
  var score = 0;
  const divScore = document.getElementById("score");


  // PARTE DEI LISTENERS per il gioco

  // Aggiungo un listener ad ogni oggetto per "ascoltare" quando inizia il drag 
  oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  });

  // Aggiungo più listener ad ogni elemento per "ascoltare" cosa succede tra l'inizio del drag e la sua fine (drop)
  contenitoreElements.forEach(ogg => {
    ogg.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto è posizionato sopra ad un contenitore
    ogg.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto è rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore
    ogg.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto va via da un contenitore
    ogg.addEventListener("drop", drop); // "Ascolta" se un oggetto viene rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore
  });


  // PARTE DEGLI EVENTI DRAG AND DROP per il gioco

  // Evento "inizio a prendere un oggetto"
  function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  }

  // Se un oggetto viene posizioneto sopra al contenitore, viene aggiunto "contenitore-over" alla classe del contenitore
  // Determina l'effetto visivo dell'ingrandirsi di un contenitore quando un oggetto viene trascinato sopra
  function dragEnter(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
      event.target.classList.add("contenitore-hover");
    }
  }

  // "Lascia il comando all'itente": evita la gestione di default e impedisce che venga droppato in automatico
  function dragOver(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
      event.preventDefault();
      /* developer.mozilla.org
      Il metodo preventDefault() dell'interfaccia Event dice all'user agent che se l'evento non viene esplicitamente gestito, 
      la sua azione predefinita non dovrebbe essere presa come normalmente. L'evento continua a propagarsi come al solito, 
      a meno che uno dei suoi listener di eventi non chiami stopPropagation() o stopImmediatePropagation(), uno dei due 
      interrompa la propagazione contemporaneamente. */
    }
  }

  /* Se un oggetto viene posizionato sopra ad un contenitore, esso viene ingrandito dalla funzione dragEnter.
  Se poi il giocatore "cambia idea", e trascina lontano dal contenitore il suo oggetto, esso deve tornare della misura iniziale
  Rimuovo "contenitore-over" dalla classe del contenitore */
  function dragLeave(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropped")) {
      event.target.classList.remove("contenitore-hover");
    }
  }


  var counterRightDropped = 0;

  /* gestione del rilascio/drop: Se l'oggetto viene rilasciato sopra ad un contenitore:
  - il contenitore ritorna della misura iniziale di default (come in dragLeave, viene rimosso "contenitore-over" dalla classe)
  - viene fatto un confronto tra l'id parziale dell'oggetto e l'id accettabile dal contenitore.
  - Se l'abbinamento è giusto (ossia confronto = true), viene aggiunto "dragged" alla classe dell'oggetto, facendo in modo che non sia più disponibile 
    (effetto visivo css) ne' prendibile (draggable=false)
  - Viene incrementato o decrementato il contatore del punteggio a seconda dell'esisto del confronto */
  function drop(event) {

    event.target.classList.remove("contenitore-hover");
    const idAccettabileContenitore = event.target.getAttribute("idAccettabile"); // Prendo l'id che il contenitore accetta
    const idOggetto = event.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // Con dragStart ho settato l'attributo text a "event.target.id". Qui lo riprendo (ex: "11")
    const sottostringaID = idOggetto.substr(0, 3); // Sottostringa dell'id dell'oggetto (ex. da "13" a "1")

    const vita1 = document.getElementById("vita1");
    const vita2 = document.getElementById("vita2");
    const vita3 = document.getElementById("vita3");

    const giocabutton = document.getElementById('gioca');
    const nuovaPart = document.getElementById("nuovaPartita");

    if (sottostringaID === idAccettabileContenitore) {
      const oggettoGiusto = document.getElementById(idOggetto);
      oggettoGiusto.classList.add("dragged");
      oggettoGiusto.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
      score++;
      counterRightDropped++;
      divScore.innerText = "Punteggio: " + score;
    } else {

      if (vita1.style.visibility === "visible") {
        vita1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else if (vita3.style.visibility === "visible") {
        vita3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }

      score = score - 2;
      divScore.innerText = "Punteggio: " + score;
      vite = vite - 1;

      if (vite == 0) {
        vita2.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert("GAME OVER! \nVite-Alberelli esauriti! \nPunteggio finale: " + score);
        }, 20)
        clearInterval(timerOggetti);

        nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }

    if (counterRightDropped === 16) {
      giocabutton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      oggettoElements.forEach(ogg => {
        ogg.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-check-circle oggetto");
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("HAI VINTO! \nPunteggio finale: " + score);
      }, 50)
      clearInterval(timerOggetti);

      nuovaPart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, gold, limegreen);
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font: bold 52px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902;
}

h1:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 2px 2px #fe4902, 3px 3px #fe4902, 4px 4px #fe4902, 5px 5px #fe4902, 6px 6px #fe4902;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#time {
  color: navy;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#score {
  color: blue;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: orange;
  font: bold 34px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  color: navy;
  font: bold 24px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #02a2fe, 2px 2px #02a2fe, 3px 3px #02a2fe;
  text-align: center;
}

.oggettoElements {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 32px;
}

.oggetto {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0px 8px;
  cursor: move;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.oggetto:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.contenitore {
  height: 104px;
  width: 128px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px dashed #111;
  transition: border-width 0.2s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.4s;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.contenitore span {
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* The element is never the target of pointer events */
}

.contenitore.contenitore-hover {
  border-width: 5px;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.contenitore.dropped {
  border-style: solid;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenitore.dropped i {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.oggetto.dragged {
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: default;
}

.oggetto.dragged:hover {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.tabella {
  height: 70%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body>section {
  display: table;
  align: center;
}

section.oggettoElements {
  display: table-row;
}

section.oggettoElements>div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

section.oggettoElements>div>div {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

div>span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center
}

#gioca {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

.tree {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexalberi {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nuovaPartita {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>GAME</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSTEST.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JSTEST.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div onClick="GoToMainMenu();">
    <h1>Trash CAN or trash CAN't?</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="gioca" onclick="timerApparizioni();">
    <h2><u>GIOCA</u>
      <h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Abbina il rifiuto al bidone giusto!</h3>
  </div>


  <div id="nuovaPartita" onClick="history.go(0);" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <h2>GIOCA ANCORA</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="score">Punteggio: 0</div>

  <!-- section contenente le vite-alberelli -->
  <section class="flexalberi">
    <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita1" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita2" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-tree tree" id="vita3" style="color: #008000; visibility:visible;"></i>
  </section>

  <!-- section contenente i contenitori (fissi) in cui andranno trascinati gli oggetti -->
  <section class="contenitore-elements flexcontainer">
    <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-1" style="color: #0000FF;"><span>Carta</span></div>
    <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-2" style="color: #008000;"><span>Vetro</span></div>
    <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-3" style="color: #FFD700;"><span>Plastica</span></div>
    <div class="fas fa-trash contenitore" idAccettabile="c-4" style="color: #8B4513;"><span>Organico</span></div>
  </section>

  <!-- Tabella contenente gli oggetti che appariranno sullo schermo durante la partita -->
  <section class="tabella">
    <section class="oggettoElements">
      <div class="fas fa-prescription-bottle oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-32">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-bone oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-42">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-flask oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-22">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-box-open oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-12">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
      <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-11">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-21">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-31">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-41">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
      <div class="far fa-hourglass oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-23">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-drumstick-bite oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-43">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="far fa-map oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-13">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-utensils oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-33">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
      <div class="far fa-file oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-14">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fas fa-cookie-bite oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-44">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-shopping-bag oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-34">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fas fa-vial oggetto" draggable="true" style="color: #000000;" id="c-24">
        <div><span></span></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Basically by calling jQuery's document ready function. `$(function() {});`

You have to make sure the dom has time to finish loading all the elements on the page before you access them with javascript.

I also removed the following commented code as it was improperly commented for javascript syntax.

```
// ORIGINALE prof:
<!-- $(document).ready(function(){ -->
    <!-- $('#runme').click(function(){ -->
        <!-- let SIZE = 4 -->
        <!-- let r = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1; -->
        <!-- let c = (Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE)) + 1; -->
        <!-- $( "section.oggettoElements:nth-of-type("+r+") i:nth-child("+c+")" ).css( "color", "#FF0000" ); -->
    <!-- }); -->
<!-- }); -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So this code is "doing something" on your computer? By hitting "GIOCA" (play) it should slowly make objects appear on the lower half of the window. And meanwhile you should be able to drag them to one of the four bins.

Comment: Replace `$(function()` with `window.addEventListener("load",function()` and you can delete jquery

Comment: Yes, javascript is working and functioning in the snippet above. You can try it out, but I didn't fix all the issues with the code. I just got it working for you. Please mark as answered if this moves you past the problem you were facing.

Comment: Thanks. 
I'm sorry, but it still doesn't work for me. I don't understand why, but if it is all on a single file it works without any issue. when we "break" it like you did, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: My code actually runs -  I did not understand that you need to go full screen.